# docusign POST template to a folder using REST API not working

Tags: php, docusignapi

How to post docusign template in a specified folder? so far as per API I have used

```
"envelopeTemplateDefinition" => array(
     "name"=> 'SpecialTPL_'. 'TestName',
     "folderName" => "testFolder",
     "folderId" => "A Long ID fetched earlier by API's /folders call",
     "folderUri" => "/folders/A Long ID fetched earlier by API's /folders call",
)
```

But this is posting templates nto default "template" Folder only, and not into "testFolder".

Comment: I have not been able to test this but i do not see folderUri as an argument for this API call. https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Template.htm?Highlight=envelopeTemplateDefinition

Comment: @LuisScott yes, folderName is valid argument, but that didn't worked so I just tested with adding more arguments and changes, but anything didn't worked.

Comment: To add to my answer: It doesn't appear that providing a custom template Subfolder for a folderId is currently supported in the original template POST request. The template defaults to being placed into the Parent folder (i.e. My Templates). It's unfortunate that the call succeeds to place the template in the Parent folder without error even when defining your subfolder folderId in the request.

Answer (score 1):

The POST request defaults to the template being placed into the Parent folder (i.e. My Templates) regardless of the fact that you specified your subfolder folderId.

You'll need to first run your template POST call, then a Move Envelope (Template) PUT call after to place the template into the subfolder. Steps would be:

1) POST your Template into the default folder i.e. POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account ID]/templates

2) GET your Template Subfolder and Parent Folder folderIds i.e. GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account ID]/folders?template=only

3) PUT a Move Template request using the Subfolder and Parent Folder folderIds returned in step 2 i.e. https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/[account ID]/folders/[subfolder ID]

Your JSON body for step 3 would be:

{

"envelopeIds": ["*Template ID returned in step 1*"],

"fromFolderId": "*Parent Template Folder ID returned in step 2*"

}

***Note that envelopeIds is a list of template IDs and the IDs themselves need to be wrapped by [ ] even if your only specifying just one template***

Comment: I had to do something different for *step2*, in order to get the current template for the newly created template I used:

`/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}` then I grabbed `folderId` and used that one on step3.

For step 3: `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}` where folderId is the target folder and in the payload `fromFolderId` is the one I got on step2